# Spanish stemming in Oracle Text

Tags: oracle, oracle-text, stem

I'm trying to create an Oracle Text index to make FTS queries on some text columns in Spanish in the database.
According to Oracle docs I need to create a LEXER and a WORDLIST to enable stem and fuzzy queries:

```
exec ctxsys.ctx_ddl.create_preference ('cust_lexer','BASIC_LEXER');
exec ctxsys.ctx_ddl.set_attribute ('cust_lexer','base_letter','YES');
exec ctxsys.ctx_ddl.set_attribute ('cust_lexer','index_stems','SPANISH');
exec ctxsys.ctx_ddl.create_preference('cust_wordlist','BASIC_WORDLIST');
exec ctxsys.ctx_ddl.set_attribute('cust_wordlist','stemmer','AUTO');
exec ctxsys.ctx_ddl.set_attribute('cust_wordlist','fuzzy_match','AUTO');
```

And then create the index using those preferences:

```
CREATE INDEX NOMBREACCION_CTX ON ACCION(NOMBRE_ACCION) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT parameters ('LEXER cust_lexer WORDLIST cust_wordlist');
```

When I run a query using stem operator ($) I get the following error:

```
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-00100: internal error, arguments : [50935],[drpn.c],[1113],[],[]
DRG-00100: internal error, arguments : [50935],[drpnw.c],[651],[],[]
DRG-00100: internal error, arguments : [51002],[drwa.c],[597],[],[]
DRG-00100: internal error, arguments : [51029],[drwas.c],[498],[ACCION],[]
DRG-51023: stemmer file cannot be opened
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.  
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.
```

According to Oracle docs stem feature should work for Spanish: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/amultlng.htm#CCREF2294

Also, this doesn't seem to be a missing feature in Oracle XE: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/doc.112/e21743/toc.htm#XERDM105

If i change 'SPANISH' for 'ENGLISH' it works OK. Has anyone managed to setup Spanish stemming in Oracle Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found that Spanish stemming works OK in full Oracle Installations. 
For stemming, Oracle requires a dictionary that is not available in Oracle XE installations. Only English and Japanese dictionaries are installed with Oracle XE.